# How to detect the empty value or unset key in array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$requiredKey = ['name', 'type', 'costPrice', 'salePrice'];  
$newArr = ["costPrice" => "45",
        "name" => "133",
        "productType" => "456",
        "remark" => "4545",
        "salePrice" => "454545",
        "saleType" => "789"];
foreach ($requiredKey as $key) {
    if($newArr[$key] == null) {
        //Why this place always is true?
        echo 'null';
        return false;
    }
    $insertData[$key] = $newArr[$key];
}
```

Those code used to detect the value is unset or empty, and sometime the value of key is not empty, but it always return true?

Comment: You can use `isset` or `array_key_exists` to check for a certain key in your array.

Comment: `if(!isset($newArr[$key])) echo "Value not set";` or `if(!array_key_exists($key, $newArr)) echo "Key doesn't exist in array";` More about `array_key_exists`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Your code returns false for me. It does throw an undefined index as expected with this type of check, but it does return false.

Answer (score 0):

`isset` will do in most cases, `array_key_exists` is more "accurate" as it will detect also null values set (as opposed to not set at all.

```
isset($a['x']) --> false
array_key_exist('x', $a) --> false
$a['x'] = 1;
isset($a['x']) --> true
array_key_exist('x', $a) --> true
$a['x'] = null;
isset($a['x']) --> false
array_key_exist('x', $a) --> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `empty` instead.

```
$requiredKey = ['name', 'type', 'costPrice', 'salePrice'];  
$newArr = ["costPrice" => "45",
        "name" => "133",
        "productType" => "456",
        "remark" => "4545",
        "salePrice" => "454545",
        "saleType" => "789"];
foreach ($requiredKey as $key) {
    if(empty($newArr[$key])) {
        echo 'null';
        return false;
    }
    $insertData[$key] = $newArr[$key];
}
```

`empty` will return true if array key doesn't exists or array key exists with null value.

Comment: Just remember if you use empty that there are many other values besides null that are considered empty. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues